# Validation Forms that were loaded via Ajax into jquery-ui tabs

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery-ui tab example to add extra tabs. I changed that code to be able to add tabs that load a form via Ajax. I was able to create that just changing these:

```
var $tabs = $( "#tabs").tabs({
    cache: true,
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='formularioAgricola.php' id='#{label}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>"
    //ajaxOptions: a        
});
```

So I changed the tabTemplate to load the same Form always.

**My problem is** that I'm not sure how to retrieve, either to tell that every tag from that form use jquery-ui stuff, like buttons, datepickers, etc.

In a regular form I would do something like:

```
$("#btnRevisar").button()
```

But when we talk about form load via Ajax it is different.

and also, how can I try to differ one form from other one, if they are all named with the same name, **is it possible?**

Thanks guys

Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the tabs docs page, tab titled "Events" there is a "load" event. The "ui" argument gives you access to an object that includes the current panel that is loaded. If you are using same ID on forms, beware that ID's must be unique in a page.

```
var $tabs = $( "#tabs").tabs({
    cache: true,
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='formularioAgricola.php' id='#{label}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",

    /* add new option for load event*/

    load: function( event, ui){
        var $currTabContentPanel=$(ui.panel);
        /* only look in currently loaded content for formClass*/
        $currTabContentPanel.find('.formClass').doSomething()

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, and yeah I know that having same ID is wrong, but I'm not sure how to change it if I'm currecntly loading the same form via Ajax, is there any way when I call the form, to add something to his ID, or in other case when the form is called to recieve a variable as a ID?

Comment: why is ID so important? change it to class instead and you can always look for it from the tab ID